# UICollectionView retain cell view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am having a webview inside UICollectionView cell. If cells on the screen are loaded and if I scroll down new cells gets loaded but if I again scroll back to top the very first cell which earlier had WebView loaded completely loads the webview again from start. Is there any way to manage this scenario so that end user will not see webview at same position loading again and again.

PS I am loading local data into webview but since it contains charts and heavy rendering it is taking few seconds to load the cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
        DashboardViewController.cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! 
        CustomCollectionViewCell

        cell.loadHTMLData()
           return  cell
    }
```

Here cellForItemAtIndexPath for indexpath 0 would get called multiple times if iI scroll down and then scroll up again. This is causing my cells showing loading indicators again and again even if that cell and data was loaded earlier.

Comment: Show your cell code.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Here is the code.

Comment: Show full code what you have done, what is inside loadHTMLData()

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem while loading contents from datasource methods.

This is also a bad approach since you are wasting bandwidth every time the cell comes into picture.

The easiest way for you to achieve a smooth experience is to cache the data you have downloaded.

You can look into the solution of caching online if you want a very robust caching logic but I assume a simple dictionary of `<String: Data>` will suffice(where `String` is the identifier for that particular cell and I am not talking about the `cellIdentifier` you use while registering or dequeing a cell. You can use `UUID` or `hash` or some other technique that suits you best).

So in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you will check if the data is  present in the cache for that particular cell. If it is then fetch it from the cahce(i.e `Data`) otherwise fetch from API. Simple as that.

Comment: Thanks Rishab but I have already cached the data. I am using a javascript engine to load chart data. which takes 2 3 seconds to load chart once it is given the chart data. I am caching the chart data but loading chart alone takes considerable time. Is there any way I can retain the entire view?

Comment: And this chart data you are talking about, is that what you load in `webView`?

Comment: Yes.. I figured out he solution and I have put that in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I applied a small trick and it worked.

I put a optional variable **indexPath** in my custom collectionview class

```
var indexPath : IndexPath?
```

then in cellForItemAtIndexPath method I checked if the cell.indexPath is not null and has same value as that of cellForItemAtIndexPath method. If it is same I am directly returning the cell without loading HTML again.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
    DashboardViewController.cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! 
    CustomCollectionViewCell

    if let cellIndexPath = cell.indexPath {
        if cellIndexPath == indexPath {
            return cell // This is the cell with preloaded HTML so return it directly 
        }
    }

    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.loadHTMLData()
       return  cell
}
```